# Употребление глагола «разнообразить»

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Правильно ли написано следующее предложение?
**Искусственное светило будет разнообразить ночной пейзаж областного центра в течении недели.**
В данном случае интересует, правильно ли употреблять вместе слова "будет разнообразить"?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: Как правильно пишется «в течении» или «в течение»?  https://obrazovaka.ru/kak-pishetsya/v-techenii.html#ixzz5Vs72DVOR

Comment: Сама идя о том, что один объект может разнообразить пейзах в течение недели, неверна. Разнообразие подразумевает постоянную смену образов, а тут одно и то же не меняется целую неделю! Разве что это искусственное светило само по себе переменчиво

Comment: Дополнительное освещение изменит обычные  пейзажи (виды),     создаст новые образы города. Можно целую неделю ходить и фотографировать. Разве это  не разнообразие?

Comment: @Ксения Светило один раз все изменит. А разнообразить в течение недели значит постоянно что-то менять (например, каждый день) . Но если оно будет двигаться и переливаться, тогда согласен.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, выражение "**будет разнообразить**" в данном контексте допустимо. Оно придаёт предложению такой смысл: *И. светило **внесёт** в ночной пейзаж **разнообразие** своим присутствием в течение такого-то времени.* Понятие *разнообразия* всегда охватывает предмет *в целом* (в пространстве или времени), а не только в той части, где наблюдается отличие одной части от другой. Когда что-то делается "для разнообразия", это самое *разнообразие* понимается в соотношении с предшествующим положением дел, а не само по себе (якобы что-то с некоторого момента "стало разнообразным").

Comment: В Нацкорпусе нет выражения "будет разнообразить", значит, частотность его невелика. Дело в то, что форма "разнообразит" (сов. вид, что сделает) имеет значение "сделает разнообразным", "внесет разнообразие" в привычные городские пейзажи, в течение недели они будут восприниматься по-новому. По-моему, автор текста хотел сказать именно это, но  его смутила форма "будет разнообразить", непривычная для слуха в силу своей низкой частотности употребления.

Answer (score 1):

Искусственное светило **на неделю  разнообразит** ночной пейзаж областного центра.

В данном случае лучше использовать глагол совершенного вида: (что сделает) – разнообразит.

Выражение "будет разнообразить" используется редко и поэтому непривычно для слуха, хотя с точки зрения грамматики оно возможно.

Примечания

1) Глагол "разнообразить" может использоваться  как двувидовой, хотя в словарях чаще указывается только несовершенный вид.

Примеры:

Несовершенный вид: Это очень их бодрит, дает импульс, разнообразит будни… [Дина Рубина. Несколько торопливых слов любви (2001) // «Новый Мир», 2003]

Совершенный вид: Возможно, такое решение разнообразит и скрасит жизнь ваших питомцев. [Елизавета Мельникова. Дом для Тобика (2003) // «Сад своими руками», 2003.07.15]

2) Если это художественно-публицистический (газетный) текст, то из предложения желательно убрать слова делового  характера  (в течение недели, областной центр).

Возможное редактирование: *Искусственное светило разнообразит (преобразит)  ночные пейзажи города на всю неделю.

Answer (score 1):

Сама идя о том, что один объект может разнообразить пейзах в течение недели, неверна. Разнообразие подразумевает постоянную смену образов, а тут одно и то же не меняется целую неделю! Посему предлагаю такой вариант:

**На следующей неделе искусственное светило изменит ночной пейзаж областного центра.**

Но возможно, это искусственное светило само по себе переменчиво и своей игрой вносит разнообразие. Тогда можно уйти от спорных построений с глаголом *разнообразить* и написать:

**Искусственное светило будет вносить разнообразие в ночной пейзаж областного центра в течение недели.**

Comment: Интересно, в каком стиле написан ваш текст?  Это деловой отчет комиссии  по подготовке города к празднику?  Для газетной статьи не подойдет: почти все слова - это канцелярские штампы, а там текст должен быть художественно-эмоциональным.

Comment: @Ксения, я старался далеко не уходить от оригинала. Нас ведь не спрашивали о художественных достоинствах текста.  В принципе, я тоже не поклонник такого стиля.

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова (здесь же и другие — Ушакова, Ожегова, Ефремовой, МАС):
[разнообра́зить](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -ражу, -разишь; *нсв.* что. Делать разнообразным.
*Разнообразить будничную жизнь. Разнообразить приёмы художественного творчества. Разнообразить стол, закуску.*
◁ Разнообразиться, -зится; страд.

В словаре управления (Д. Э. Розенталь):
[разнообразить](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2105/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — **что чем.** *Разнообразить литературные вечера художественным чтением и музыкой.*

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) утверждает, что глагол двувидовой, т. е. может образовывать формы совершенного и несовершенного вида. В будущем времени — буду/будешь… разнообра́зить.

Нашлись и примеры использования.

*Может, к тому времени Анька подрастет и станет собеседником, **будет разнообразить** мою одинокую деревенскую жизнь.*
[С. Чуев. Настоящее лето Димки Бобрикова](https://books.google.ee/books?id=j-guDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=7wCWckUBSp&sig=gj9oQ1PmwIQNzO2IqEg77cU648o&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAyI2LvLreAhUIjSwKHYRRAZ04ChDoATAJegQIAhAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

*"Хорошо было бы обосноваться в этом районе, по крайней мере **буду разнообразить** время прогулками по лесу, не то здесь от тоски с ума сойти можно", — думал он, переходя с вопросами от дома к дому* (И. Головкина. Побежденные).

Получается, что сочетание *будет разнообразить* вполне употребимо (смысл и стиль указанного предложения не разбираю).

Answer (score 0):

Стилистически такой вариант явно неудачен. 
"Будет" можно опустить без всякого ущерба для смысла и грамматики. 
***"Искусственное светило разнообразит ночной пейзаж областного центра в течение недели"*** - это явно лучше.

А вот ответить, является ли исходный вариант ошибочным грамматически или просто стилистически неудачным, затруднительно.

С эти глаголом "разнообразить" вообще большие странности. Словари обычно подают его как глагол несовершенного вида (БТС Кузнецова, например), однако совершенно очевидно, что это глагол двухвидовой, как минимум - в отдельных формах. Хотя тут скорее спорен именно несовершенный вид: "Я разноображу" безусловно воспринимается как форма будущего времени, а настоящее требует чего-то наподобие *"я разнообораживаю"* - по образцу частично двухвидового глагола "организовать" ("организую", "организовываю"). Но такой формы ("разноображивать", "разноображиваю") словари не фиксируют. Получается, "разнообразить" может выступать в роли несовершенного вида во всех личных формах и всех грамматических временах.

Таким образом о грамматической ошибочности "будет разнообразить" остается открытым. 
В таких случаях обычно руководствуются принципом "разрешено все, что не запрещено явно". Следовательно, признать грамматически ошибочной такую фразу нельзя.
Но это чисто академические рассуждения. Практически, как уже сказал, её безусловно надо править в плане стилистики.

И, как уже подсказали, "в течениЕ".

Comment: Мне кажется, что надо ещё и _в течениИ_ поправить.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Да!!! Не заметил. Спасибо!

Comment: Если речь идёт о банальной длительности, то "в течени**е**"; если же скучное _течение_ недели оживилось явлением искуственного светила, то иное написание можно рассматривать как литературный приём :).